# Unexpected Token Error when binding variable to child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives. One being the child of the other:

```
.directive("mbVideo", function(mbFileReader){

  return {

    restrict : "EA",
    scope: {
        "videoModel" : '=model'
    },
    templateUrl: 'mbUpload/mbVideo.tpl.html',

    link: function($scope,el, attr){


    }
  };
 })

.directive("mbVideoThumb", function(){

    return {

        restrict : "EA",
        scope: {
            "thumbModel" : '=thumbModel',
            "videoModel" : '=videoModel'
        },
        template: '<mb-video model="{{videoModel}}"></mb-video> <input ng-click="getThumb()" type="button" value="Thumbnail"><img id="{{thumbId}}" class="mb-video-thumb" src="{{thumb}}">',

        link: function($scope,elem, attr){


        }
    };
 });
```

I am getting this error: "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'videoModel' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{videoModel}}] starting at [videoModel}}]."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that videoModel is a string; if you have a Angular binding in quotes and the bound variable is a string, Angular will error. Luckily, there is an easy fix:

```
model="'{{videoModel}}'"
```